# Logic behind creating a traffic light using sfml

Tags: graphics, sfml

I am trying to write a code to design a simple traffic light. However, I cannot figure out the maths behind it. Can someone help me with the logic?
saying, X is the length and Y is the width...I need to divide the rectangle into 3 equal parts and then position the coloured circles on it.

Comment: What have you tried? What are you struggling with?

Comment: You want to get the midpoints for the lights? Something like this?
x_i = x/2, y_i = y/6*(2i+1)

Comment: so, I have drawn a rectangle (x,y) and I need to draw a circle in its center. I am unable to figure out how to calculate the radius with respect to the width of the rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could take the following design for your application.
[image]

Or if you don't want to take squares as building blocks:
[image]

However this could result in a bad geometry if you don't choose epsilon carefully.

Comment: Note that on graphics devices the ordinate (y-axis) usually is oriented into opposite direction and origin is at top-left. Apart from, nice work...